# Tag for subclass of NSView returning -1

Tags: swift, uiview, nsview

I have a class that is a subclass of `NSView`. When an instance of this view is clicked, it runs `notificationCenter.post(name: .tileClicked, object: tag)`. However, the tag is always -1. How do I ensure that my subclass has a tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `tag` property of `NSView` returns -1.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1483248-tag) If you want it to return a different value, you must create a subclass of `NSView` in which you override the property. (This is different from `UIView`, which has a mutable `tag` property.)